# making movie from output txt matplotlib

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, movie

I'm trying to use matplotlib to make a movie from a txt output file containing the solution of an n-body problem. The basic thing I need to do is select lines with a certain time difference in the output file (in the close encounters the timestep becomes smaller to maintain precision so I get more output lines) and make a movie using these. Each line of the output file I'm using contains a time and the positions of different particles.

Online I've found many tutorials for animating with matplotlib (for instance to animate a sine wave) but I can't seem to find any tutorial helping me achieve the goal of using the a txt file to make a movie with it.

Here is an example of a few lines from the output file I'm using:

> 0.0005  -2  -1  1  -1  1  3
>   0.1505  -1.99288  -0.998912  0.99496  -0.997876  0.998912  2.99501
>   0.3005  -1.97152  -0.995647  0.97983  -0.991519  0.995647  2.98006
>   0.4505  -1.93558  -0.990164  0.954369  -0.980896  0.990164  2.95504
>   0.6005  -1.88448  -0.982387  0.918153  -0.965948  0.982391  2.91976
>   0.7505  -1.81732  -0.972201  0.870528  -0.946598  0.972217  2.87393
>   0.9005  -1.73279  -0.959441  0.810535  -0.922745  0.959494  2.81716
>   1.0505  -1.62897  -0.943865  0.736769  -0.894279  0.944017  2.74895
>   1.2005  -1.50304  -0.925119  0.647125  -0.861093  0.925512  2.66865
>   1.3505  -1.35056  -0.902646  0.538279  -0.82313  0.903612  2.57541
>   1.5005  -1.16395  -0.875477  0.404466  -0.780528  0.877819  2.46818
>   1.6505  -0.92788  -0.84154  0.233839  -0.734119  0.847441  2.34559
>   1.7829  -0.644524  -0.800616  0.0259867  -0.693428  0.816054  2.2232
>   1.8129  -0.560299  -0.78792  -0.0367125  -0.685743  0.808253  2.19346
>   1.8429  -0.459578  -0.771672  -0.112441  -0.680428  0.800171  2.16294
>   1.85368  -0.416242  -0.763979  -0.145323  -0.679882  0.797195  2.15178
>   1.85655  -0.403697  -0.761621  -0.154881  -0.679979  0.796398  2.14879
>   1.85919  -0.391633  -0.75928  -0.16409  -0.680198  0.795662  2.14604
>   1.86161  -0.380057  -0.756956  -0.172945  -0.680536  0.794983  2.1435
>   1.86383  -0.368974  -0.754647  -0.181438  -0.680989  0.794361  2.14118
>   1.86584  -0.35839  -0.75235  -0.189563  -0.681555  0.793793  2.13906
>   1.86767  -0.348313  -0.750063  -0.197316  -0.682229  0.793277  2.13713
>   1.86932  -0.338746  -0.747786  -0.204689  -0.683008  0.79281  2.13539
>   1.8708  -0.329696  -0.745515  -0.211678  -0.683887  0.792391  2.13383
>   1.87212  -0.321167  -0.743249  -0.218277  -0.684864  0.792017  2.13244
>   1.87329  -0.313163  -0.740986  -0.224481  -0.685933  0.791685  2.1312
>   1.87432  -0.305688  -0.738724  -0.230285  -0.68709  0.791393  2.13012
>   1.87521  -0.298747  -0.73646  -0.235685  -0.688332  0.791138  2.12917
>   1.87599  -0.292342  -0.734192  -0.240677  -0.689654  0.790917  2.12835
>   1.87665  -0.286477  -0.731918  -0.245255  -0.691052  0.790728  2.12764
>   1.87721  -0.281154  -0.729636  -0.249417  -0.69252  0.790568  2.12705
>   1.87768  -0.276376  -0.727345  -0.25316  -0.694055  0.790434  2.12655
>   1.87806  -0.272145  -0.72504  -0.256478  -0.695652  0.790323  2.12614
>   1.87838  -0.268462  -0.722721  -0.259371  -0.697306  0.790233  2.1258
>   1.87863  -0.265328  -0.720385  -0.261833  -0.699012  0.79016  2.12553
>   1.87884  -0.262746  -0.71803  -0.263865  -0.700766  0.790102  2.12532
>   1.879  -0.260714  -0.715653  -0.265462  -0.702564  0.790055  2.12514
>   1.87913  -0.259235  -0.713253  -0.266623  -0.704399  0.790017  2.125
>   1.87925  -0.258306  -0.710827  -0.267346  -0.706268  0.789985  2.12488
>   1.87935  -0.257929  -0.708373  -0.26763  -0.708165  0.789955  2.12477
>   1.87945  -0.258103  -0.705889  -0.267473  -0.710086  0.789926  2.12466
>   1.87957  -0.258825  -0.703373  -0.266876  -0.712025  0.789893  2.12454
>   1.87971  -0.260095  -0.700823  -0.265836  -0.713978  0.789853  2.12439
>   1.87987  -0.261911  -0.698236  -0.264354  -0.71594  0.789805  2.12422
>   1.88008  -0.264272  -0.695611  -0.26243  -0.717906  0.789745  2.12399
>   1.88035  -0.267173  -0.692945  -0.260063  -0.719871  0.78967  2.12371
>   1.88067  -0.270613  -0.690236  -0.257255  -0.72183  0.789576  2.12336
>   1.88107  -0.274589  -0.687483  -0.254006  -0.723778  0.789462  2.12294
>   1.88155  -0.279096  -0.684683  -0.250318  -0.72571  0.789324  2.12243
>   1.88213  -0.284131  -0.681835  -0.24619  -0.727621  0.789159  2.12182
>   1.8828  -0.289691  -0.678936  -0.241626  -0.729507  0.788964  2.12109
>   1.8836  -0.29577  -0.675984  -0.236626  -0.731362  0.788736  2.12025
>   1.88451  -0.302363  -0.672978  -0.231194  -0.733181  0.788473  2.11927
>   1.88556  -0.309466  -0.669916  -0.22533  -0.734959  0.788171  2.11815
>   1.88675  -0.317072  -0.666795  -0.219039  -0.736692  0.787828  2.11688
>   1.88809  -0.325177  -0.663613  -0.212322  -0.738375  0.78744  2.11544
>   1.88959  -0.333773  -0.66037  -0.205184  -0.740002  0.787004  2.11383
>   1.89127  -0.342855  -0.657062  -0.197626  -0.741568  0.786518  2.11203

The first line is the time, the second and third the x- and y-positions of the first particle and so on for a second and third particle. So the goal I'm trying to achieve is basically make a movie using this output file showing the movement of the particles with correct times (the time has to flow at the same rate during the movie). Anyone know how to do such a thing?

Comment: I'd recommend adding an example of the output file lines to help people get a better sense of the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, i just added an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code should do what you want. The basic idea is to interpolate the coordinates from the simulation output so that you can plot them at equal timesteps.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

class AnimatedScatter(object):
    def __init__(self, t, xpositions, ypositions):
        self.fig = plt.figure()
        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.sim_data = np.dstack((xpositions, ypositions))
        self.t = t

        nframes = len(t)

        self.ani = animation.FuncAnimation(self.fig, self.update,\
                                           frames=np.arange(nframes),\
                                           init_func=self.setup_plot)

    def setup_plot(self):
        self.scat = self.ax.scatter(self.sim_data[0,:,0], self.sim_data[0,:,1])
        self.fig.suptitle("t = %f" % (self.t[0]))
        return [self.scat]

    def update(self, i):
        self.scat.set_offsets(self.sim_data[i])
        self.fig.suptitle("t = %f" % (self.t[i]))
        return [self.scat]

    def show(self):
        plt.show()

data = np.genfromtxt("data.txt")

tsim = data[:,0]
xsim = data[:,1::2]
ysim = data[:,2::2]

nframes = 100
nparts = xsim.shape[1]

tplot = np.linspace(tsim[0], tsim[-1], nframes)

xplot = np.empty( (nframes, nparts) )
yplot = np.empty( (nframes, nparts) )

for i in xrange( nparts ):
    xspl = interp1d(tsim, xsim[:,i])
    yspl = interp1d(tsim, ysim[:,i])

    xplot[:,i] = xspl(tplot)
    yplot[:,i] = yspl(tplot)

a = AnimatedScatter(tplot, xplot, yplot)
a.show()
```